# How to compile Android AOSP for x86

Tags: android, x86, android-source

I've seen that there are emulator images available for Android which can run on x86 virtual machines. I'd like to build my own x86 Android image from source, but I can't seem to find instructions online. Is it currently possible to build a custom x86 "ROM"? (not sure "ROM" is appropriate term for x86 systems, whatever)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, but you still need a Linux machine to compile it (without going into a lot of troubles).

There are a lot of information on porting android to X86 platform in the net. I suggest you to start with this one: [Android-x86 - Porting Android to x86](http://www.android-x86.org/getsourcecode) .

You can also have look at `XDA forun`. They do a lot of work on porting ROM's.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks, Luis, I am already aware of Android-x86 but frankly the community is rather poor and they do things a bit differently overall from Google's main development. I'd really prefer to use AOSP on x86, at least until I can get an ARM system with virtualization.

Comment: Maybe then, you could have a look at the book `Embedded Android` from Karim Yaghmour. It's not targetting specifically X86 systems but has a good overview over the AOSP and identify the parts that are architecture dependent. Also Intel is making available the AOSP image ported to X86. Maybe you can find there some usefull information. At least for kernel compilation (which should be the though part) I remenber seeing there some information on how to compile it.